# Multi Touch Sound Triggers in Swift for iOS Development

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9

I just created a simple Xylophone app with has 7 buttons, each of which triggers an individual .wav sound. I noticed however that you cannot play two sounds (or press two of the buttons) at once. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as far as documentation to figure out how to enable this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you play a sound from a single AVAudioPlayer and then play another sound from it before the first sound is over, it will cut off the first sound. You can play two sounds simultaneously if they're coming from two different AVAudioPlayers, so you'll have to create multiple AVAudioPlayer objects to play overlapping sounds.